# Sigmoid generates predictions in a random order

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, sigmoid

Please, can you help me ? I've trained a neural networks Model with tensorflow. And when I run the activation op (sigmoid) to predict the values of the test set, it generates values in a different order than the feed_dict. How can I generate the predictions in the same order as the feed_dict ?

Here is my code for the Model :

```
apply_weights_OP = tf.matmul(X, weights, name="apply_weights")
add_bias_OP = tf.add(apply_weights_OP, bias, name="add_bias") 
activation_OP = tf.nn.sigmoid(add_bias_OP, name="activation")
```

And here is my code for the prediction :

```
test_pred = sess.run(activation_OP, feed_dict={X: test})
```

Comment: What makes you think it returns `predictions` in a different order? Could you provide example of data you pass and get as a result?

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally it returns predictions in a different order because the x of the feed dict provides from a Doc2Vec model. I trained this model a new time before I make the prediction. So it returned a new vector every time.

Comment: You're welcome.